# Office 365 API to create/update a global block list

Tags: microsoft-office-365, office365

I have been googling for sometime now and have found various APIs but none which cover what I am trying to achieve.

This [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/create-organization-wide-safe-sender-or-blocked-sender-lists-in-office-365) is what I am trying to achieve however, via an API call. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: 3.5 years later and I have this problem. I have a client that wants to edit the spam filter lists. I had a look with Microsoft APIs but nothing that points to spam filtering. I have a ps script at hand, not tested - https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4424-o365-add-sender-or-domain-to-spam-allow-list Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about setting the allow / block settings in the Exchange Control Panel it is possible through Powershell.

The configure spamfilter doc page has a [part about the Powershell Commandlets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/configure-your-spam-filter-policies#use-remote-powershell-to-configure-spam-filter-policies)

The [Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/antispam-antimalware/Set-HostedContentFilterPolicy?view=exchange-ps) will allow you to edit the list in ECP.

Comment: thanks, ill look into it. Its rather vague as it says Exchange 2013 but is under the 365 banner. I'll try work out what permissions are required and test it.